# react-scripts jest 27 version dependency error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I wanted to start testing my React component with frameworks jest and enzyme. I'm writing a code with Typescript.
So I installed packages like: **jest**, enzyme, **enzyme-adapter-react-16**, ts-jest and typescript types required dependencies. Below I show entire package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "test-learning-with-redux",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.16",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.9",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.2",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

The problem is that after installation dependencies tests works fine but react server dosen't work. I can observe error like on the screen below:

[image]

Of course I can solve this issue by adding .env with: **SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true**
and it works, but I'm not for sure if it's the best solution.

On the other hand if I delete dependency with jest by typing **npm uinstall jest**, jest won't work and there will be an error: TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function.
More on the screen below:

[image]

Below I show jest.config.js configuration file:

```
My module.exports = {
    "roots": [
        "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json",
        "node"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/src/setupEnzyme.ts"],
}
```

What's the best way to solve this problem in order to work normally with jest and typescript simultaneously? I could observe some comments where people write about forcing never version by **react-scripts** but I don't know how to do it. Maybe it's is better to stay with version from **react-scripts** and somehow solve TypeError from **jest** mentioned by me above but how?

I would be greateful for advices, prepositions.

Comment: Why have you installed many of the things react-scripts already installs again? And why add Enzyme when RTL is already available?

Comment: In One week time I will work with enzyme and jest at my work. I wanted to to train until this time. What do you propose? Which dependencies should I remove?

Comment: [hack](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/2611#issuecomment-851014990) Though this might be late, hopefully this can help someone else :)